# Nodes not connecting to Rococo relaychain

Tags: rococo, chainspec, bootnode

We are having issues with `RPC & Collator` nodes connecting to `Rococo relaychain.` The running chain works but once we restart any node, it cannot find relay peers on the `relaychain` and thus `stalls / stop` syncing. We noticed just recently because we restarted some nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any other Project having issues with connecting to the Rococo relaychain please check if you are using old relay-chain bootnodes on your collator (due to importing old polkadot). We would recommend you override it with the latest rococo chainspec. By using `-- --chain chainspec.json` and using this file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paritytech/polkadot/master/node/service/chain-specs/rococo.json